# Android/PhoneGap/SQLite app: this 'Create Virtual Table' command works on emulator, fails on device

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I have an app, using the [Lite4Cordova](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) plug-in. It's populating a virtual SQLite FS4 table from some documents on first run of the app. It runs correctly on an emulated device, but fails on a real device with an SQL error.

To open the DB, I do this:

```
        var db;
        var shortName = 'linienDB';
        var version = '1.0';
        var displayName = 'linienDB';
        var maxSize = 65535;

        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: shortName, version: version, displayName: displayName, maxSize: maxSize});
        alert("OpenDB is " + db)
```

The alert gives me "OpenDB is [object Object]" on both emulator and real device.

The create table code is this:

```
      db.transaction(function(tx){
           tx.executeSql( 'CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guidelines USING FTS4 (category, id, chapter, header, content)',[],defaultNullHandler,defaultErrorHandler);
      },defaultErrorHandler);
```

On an emulated device, this runs OK. The DB gets created & populated correctly, & I am able to run queries against it. But on my real device, the `defaultErrorHandler` is triggered on `db.transaction`,  and I get alert "Error Processing SQL: undefined". The error on the console is this:

```
12-18 17:39:08.948: V/executeSqlBatch(4375): SQLitePlugin.executeSql[Batch](): Error=near "NOT": syntax error: , while compiling: CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guidelines USING FTS4 (category, id, chapter, header, content)
```

If I switch back to the standard WebSQL DB open, like this:

```
db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
```

then the OpenDB alert is `OpenDB is [object Database]`, and the load sequence completes- but of course the table isn't built because creating an FS4 virtual table is an SQLite command, not a WebDB command.

---

UPDATE:

Following the error from LogCat that there was an error near "Not", I removed the "IF NOT EXISTS" from the Create Table statement, and just have:

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
                    tx.executeSql( 'CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE guidelines USING FTS4 (category, id, chapter, header, content)',[],defaultNullHandler,defaultErrorHandler);
                },defaultErrorHandler);
```

Which now works perfectly on the device. It's annoying not to be able to use IF NOT EXISTS syntax, but thumbs up to Android SDK for the useful error, anyway.